# How to prevent GWT from generating inline styles?

Tags: java, gwt

When I, for example, add a SimplePanel to my page I get a div like

> <div style="position: relative; " class="myClass" ...

This inline style overrides my custom style defined for  myClass.

How to prevent GWT from generating this inline style ? Or how to set it's content exlicitly to what i want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `somePanel. getElement().getStyle().setDisplay(Style.Display.BLOCK);`

Comment: not realy what U suggested but somePnel.getElement().getStyle.clearPosition() helped. Thanks for a tip.